# Is this usage of Task.Run() bad practice?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, background-service

If the use of `Task.Run` in this case justifiable ?
Currently I run this code in a WinForms app, but later on it will be used in a ASP.NET project as a `HostedService`/`BackgroundService`. I am not sure if this is comparable then.

After reading multiple blogs about async/await and `Tasks` I feel like the `Task.Run(() => ..` should be implemented in the calling method `Manager.SyncLoop()`. But what if the implementation of `IConnection` is truely asynchronous, wouldn't that be code smell ?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this should be handled by the BackgroudService, WinForms is used just for testing
        var m = new Manager();
        m.Connection = new ConnectionA();
        m.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
public interface IConnection
{
    Task<object> ReadAsync();
}

// assume that i cannot change this 
public class SomeLib
{
    private Random random = new Random();
    public object SyncReading()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return random.Next(); ;
    }
}

public class ConnectionA : IConnection
{
    private SomeLib lib = new SomeLib();
    public Task<object> ReadAsync()
    {
        // is this usage of Task.Run ok?
        var v = Task.Run(() => lib.SyncReading());
        return v;
    }

    // this will block UI
    //public Task<object> ReadAsync()
    //{
    //    return Task.FromResult(lib.SyncReading());
    //}
}

public class Manager 
{
    public IConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {          
        await SyncLoop();
    }

    public async Task SyncLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var i = await Connection.ReadAsync();

            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, can you change `IConnection`? Is this synchronous implementation the primary one, or is it just one of many?

If you can change `IConnection`, then make it synchronous, and you can [use `Task.Run` in the implementation of `ExecuteAsync`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html).

If `IConnection` needs to remain asynchronous, then I would say to implement `ConnectionA.ReadAsync` synchronously. Then have the `Task.Run` in `ExecuteAsync` as normal. The key behind this technique is that an asynchronous (`Task`-returning) signature means that the implementation *may* be asynchronous, not that it *must* be asynchronous.

Comment: I am in control of the IConnection interface. But the concrete implementation could be sync or async. Nevertheless I always want to be sure not to unnecessarily block some thread. I guess I'll go with your suggestion to implement Task.Run in the ExecuteAsync method, since I have to do it anyways (see your BackgroundService Gotcha ;) )

Comment: OK. I'd keep the `IConnection.ReadAsync` signature asynchronous, then, and just allow both asynchronous and synchronous implementations.

Comment: By "keep the singature asnychronous" you mean that I should keep the async naming and ensure asynchronous execution with the `Task.Run` call in `ExecuteAsync` ? Just for my clarification.

Comment: Yes; by "asynchronous signature", I mean the `Async` suffix and a `Task` (or tasklike) return type.